# How to find control on GridView RowCommand Event?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

i tried something like this but did not work:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Repeater)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer); 
Repeater _rpt1 = row.Cells[8].FindControl("rptReg") as Repeater;
```

error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater'.
```

is there a way i can have the below code in `OnRowCommand` event using GridView?

actually i am trying to delete the row from the gridview control and when the user click on it and i am grabbing the mulitple ids and passing to SP and update the table and `databind the gridview`

```
GridViewRow row = gv.SelectedRow;           
    Repeater _rpt = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("rptReg") as Repeater;
    Repeater _rpt1 = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].FindControl("rptVisitor") as Repeater;

    foreach (RepeaterItem item in _rpt.Items)
    {
        TextBox _txt = item.FindControl("txtId") as TextBox;
        TextBox _txt1 = item.FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;
        //update db
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow but in OnRowCommand you can check for e.CommandName == "delete"

Comment: thats correct but i have a situation where i am looking for a way to do FindControl in RowCommand?

Comment: I guess the repeaters are coming up null?  Perhaps yoy should define gv as "Gridview gv = (Gridview)sender;"

Comment: if i change to `GridView` then how you going to get `Cells`?

Comment: Are you using Repeater control inside GridView ?

Comment: RowIndex is undefined ?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
var viewRow = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvDetails.Rows)
{
    var btnSelect = (ImageButton)viewRow.FindControl("btnSelect");
    if (gvr == viewRow)
    {
        if (btnSelect.ImageUrl.ToLower() == "~/images/rbnormal.jpg")
        {
            btnSelect.ImageUrl = "~/Images/rbSelected.jpg";
            btnSelect.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        btnSelect.ImageUrl = "~/Images/rbnormal.jpg";
        btnSelect.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: gvDetails is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is telling me that the control named "rptReg" is a button.

The GridView has a property called DataKeys which can hold multiple IDs
So you would pull out the "PersonId" like:

```
     string personId = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["PersonId"].ToString();
```